# Printing help docstring of all the functions in the string module: Python

Tags: python, docstring

I am trying to print all the `functions` and their `help docstrings` in the `strings module` but am not getting the desired results. Below are the things which I have tried:

```
r = 'A random string'

1.  [help(fn) for fn in r.__dir__() if not fn.startswith('__')]
2.  [help(r.fn) for fn in r.__dir__() if not fn.startswith('__')]
3.  [fn.__doc__ for fn in r.__dir__() if not fn.startswith('__')]
4.  [r.fn.__doc__ for fn in r.__dir__() if not fn.startswith('__')]
```

and a few things more. Some of them throw errors saying that `r` does not have attribute named `'fn'`. Others just print the help documentation for the `'str'` function. Is there any way I can print this for all the functions dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python2:

```
for i in dir(r):
    if not i.startswith('__'):
        print getattr(r, i).__doc__
```

In python3:

```
for i in dir(r):
    if not i.startswith('__'):
        print(getattr(r, i).__doc__)
```

(it's basically the same, changes the `print` function only). You need to get the method object wth `getattr` in order to show its `__doc__` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

To print the docstring you use func.__doc__.

```
r = 'A random string'

for fn in r.__dir__():
  if not fn.startswith("__"):
    print ("Function:",fn)
    print (fn.__doc__)
    print()
```

Comment: Have you even tried running your code. There is an error in your first print statement. It should be `print("Function: %s" %fn)`. Furthermore, this code only prints the documentation of `str` function multiple times. Please check it once again and revert.